# Android Nullbale and NonNull: Method invocation 'getSearchableInfo' may produce 'NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, warnings, nullable, non-nullable

I have below code snippet but it shows warnings **Method invocation 'getSearchableInfo' may produce 'NullPointerException'**

```
ComponentName s = getComponentName();
if (s ==null)
    return;
@NonNull ComponentName componentName = getComponentName();
SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager
   .getSearchableInfo(componentName); //<--  Warning Line
```

I could find samples for Kotlin but I don't know how to get rid of this warning in Java?

Comment: Maybe `searchManager` could be `null`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Oh Oh! Such a mistake by me! :D Yep. You are right

Comment: almost answered :D

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `NullPointerException` calling a method with this messages:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method getSearchableInfo
```

Generally you are gettin this error when the class that call the method (`.getSearchableInfo()`) was not initialized correctly.

Be sure to initialize `SearchManager` :

```
  //Initialize SearchManager
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  ...
  ...
  SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
```